# Python Matplotlib how to adjust candlestick shadow color?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, finance

I'm following a tutorial on youtube for creating candlestick charts and ran into an interesting problem. The tutorial shows that you can edit the candlestick line color by making changes directly to the matplotlib finance.py file. The original code in the finance.py file looks like the following:

```
lines = []
patches = []
for q in quotes:
    t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]

    if close>=open :
        color = colorup
        lower = open
        height = close-open
    else           :
        color = colordown
        lower = close
        height = open-close

    vline = Line2D(
        xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
        color='k',
        linewidth=0.5,
        antialiased=True,
        )
```

Notice the vline section. The following is the code after the adjustments:

```
lines = []
patches = []
for q in quotes:
    t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]

    if close>=open :
        color = colorup
        lower = open
        height = close-open
        vline = Line2D(
            xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
            color=colorup,
            linewidth=0.5,
            antialiased=True,
            )   
    else           :
        color = colordown
        lower = close
        height = open-close
        vline = Line2D(
            xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
            color=colordown,
            linewidth=0.5,
            antialiased=True,
            )

    '''vline = Line2D(
        xdata=(t, t), ydata=(low, high),
        color='k',
        linewidth=0.5,
        antialiased=True,
        )'''
```

For reasons I can't understand the shadow still appears as black. I've tried this on two configurations.

1. Windows XP Python 2.7 Anaconda distribution Matplotlib 1.3
2. Windows 7 Python 2.7 Python(xy) distribution Matplotlib 1.3

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define colorup and colordown in the function definition? You also need to change the def to the following:

> def candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.2, colorup='k', colordown='r',
>   alpha=1.0):